# Python COM events handling blocked

Tags: python, events, com, handler

I'm working on Implementing COM in Python as I have to interact in between two different softwares(a dSPACE HIL environment & Vector CANOE environment). The idea is I change the environment variable in (CANOE) CAPL script & I would like to perform some action on the dSPACE HIL when the event happens. Right now I have not implemented any threads.

(1) So the first issue is when I try to use a simple sleep to make sure the test execution is completed in CANOE, the execution does not happen as python sleep is blocking CANoe execution & also I get **pythoncom error: Python error invoking COM method** whenever the environment variable changes. So CANOE execution starts only after sleep in Python is over & also I get the following pop up in CANOE saying Server busy.

When I use the message box, that is the user has to press the button once the test is completed execution is working fine. I'd like to replace it with some other mechanism like sleep. Kindly let me know how to fix this issue. I have pasted my script below.

```
class EnvironmentEvents:
    def __init__ ( self ) :
        print "Initializing Environment Event Class"
 
    def OnChange ( self , value ) :
        StopTestExecution = Value
        print '% 3.2f' % StopTestExecution
        print ( 'Environment Variable Value Changed' )
 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # INITIALIZE CONTROL DESK # # # # # # # # # # # 
MyControlDeskHandler = Controldesk_Handler. CONTROLDESK_HANDLER ()
 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # INITIALIZE CANOE # # # # # # # # # # # # # #  
MyCAN                = Dispatch ( 'CANoe.Application' )
MyCANMeasurement     = MyCAN. Measurement
MyCANEnvironment     = MyCAN. Environment . GetVariable ( "env_COM_BatteryVoltage" )
My events            = Dispatch WithEvents ( MyCANEnvironment , EnvironmentEvents )
 
Test Setup = MyCAN. Configuration . Test Setup
    TestEnvs = test setup. Test Environments
Testenv = TestEnvs. Item ( 1 )
Testenv. ExecuteAll ( )            
 
    ## Msgbox (0, "Test Completed", "info", 16) ## with a message box everything is working fine

    while ( StopTestExecution > 0 ):
            print '% 3.2f' % StopTestExecution
            Sleep ( 500 )
```

My idea is to send the event variable value from CAPL as 0 to stop the execution. Until that time looping has to go on.But this does not work.

(2) Then the second issue is When the OnChange event the occurs I'd like to change some thing in the dSPACE HIL Control Desk. For this I have to use a library provided by dSPACE. But the problem is how do I access this library & its methods in Events class. I tried to pass the dSPACE library object & the parameters as arguments for class EnvironmentEvents as you can see below. But python gives me the Following error. Right now I'm just using it as global & it is working fine. But I'd like to avoid it if there is a better alternative.

```
class EnvironmentEvents:
    def __init__ ( self , ControlDeskhandler , Path ) :
        print "Initializing Environment Event Class"
        self . MyHandler = ControlDeskhandler
        self . MyPath = Path
 
    def OnChange ( self , value ) :
        StopTestExecution = Value
        print '% 3.2f' % StopTestExecution
        self . MyHandler . Write_Variable ( self . MyPath , Value )
        print ( 'Environment Variable Value Changed' )

    My events             = Dispatch WithEvents(MyCANEnvironment , Environment Events ( MyControlDeskHandler ,'Model Root/VOLTAGEOUT/ Value'))
 
Traceback ( most recent call load ) :
    .     File "C: \ P rogram Files (x86) \ C ommon Files \ d SPACE \ P ython25 \ l ib \ s ite-packages \ w in32com \ c lient \ __init__.py     " , line 304 , in Dispatch WithEvents
 result_class = new . classObj ( "COMEventClass" , ( disp_class , events_class , user_event_class ) , { "__setattr__": _event_setattr_ } )
TypeError : instance ( ) takes at most 2 arguments ( 3 givenName )
[ dbg ] >>>
```

Kindly help me to fix these issues. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: The problem with `Sleep` is that it doesn't pump messages while sleeping, and COM needs messages to be processed in order to work.  (MessageBox *does* pump messages, so it works.)  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Python to tell you how to sleep while pumping messages.

Comment: Issue Resolved. As Eric has pointed out Sleep didn't allow me to pump messages & using pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages() before sleep did the magic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `Sleep` is that it doesn't pump messages while sleeping, and COM needs messages to be processed in order to work. (`MessageBox` does pump messages, so it works.)

The typical solution here is to use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` and a message pump.  Apparently `pythoncom` and `win32event` have the appropriate wrappers.

[`win32Event.MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32event__MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx_meth.html) needs a handle to wait on; if you need to wait for a specific time, then you'll be best off creating a waitable timer.  Weirdly enough, according to the docs, `win32event` has [`OpenWaitableTimer`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32event__OpenWaitableTimer_meth.html), but not `CreateWaitableTimer`.  Hopefully this is a doc error.

Anyway, if you don't need a specific time, you can just create a win32 event using [`win32event.CreateEvent`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32event__CreateEvent_meth.html).  It can be an anonymous event; all you need it for is waiting.  In your OnChange handler, you can set the event.

Once you have an event, you can wait.   Excuse my terrible python; this is transliterated from C.

```
def WaitAndPumpMessagesWithTimeout(hWaitHandle, dwMilliseconds) :
{
    fContinue = TRUE;

    while (fContinue)
        dwWaitId = win32event.MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, hWaitHandle, dwMilliseconds, win32event.QS_ALLINPUT, win32event.MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE);
        if (dwWaitId == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0)
             return TRUE;
        elif (dwWaitId ==  WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
            pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages();
        elif (dwWaitId  == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
           return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```